# ¿Como puedo obtener un int para usar con el store procedure?

Tags: java, sql

El metodo insertar tiene como parametros un String y un int, quiero tomar los datos que se obtienen del txtField pero no encuentro la manera que no me tire error y me deje obtenerlo.. En sql server los tengo declarados exactamente igual

```
art.insertar(txtPro.getText(), txtPre.getText());
```

Comment: Cual es el problema? Que el text field retorna su contenido del tipo String y precisas que se envíe un int al store procedure? txtPre.getText() retorna un String?

Comment: No, no retorna nada. Preciso que envie un int al store procedure, pero al poner txtPre.getText() no me deja ejecutarlo. Los parametros del método son string e int respectivamente

Comment: No me termina de quedar claro tu problema. Si txtPre.getText() retorna un String y tu método insertar espera un int debes convertir primero al tipo adecuado. Otro problema diferente es que txtPre.getText() retorne null o el string vacío, y si ese es el problema que planteas deberías colocar el código completo para que podamos hacernos una idea de por donde puede venir.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: que hace el metodo insertar?

Comment: Hola @FrancoJulianello, Bienvenido a [StackOverflow en Español](https://es.stackoverflow.com), te recomiendo un [tour](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) por la pagina para poder ganar tu primera medalla, y ver [como preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) para hacer un [ejemplo minimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) y la comunidad acepte de buena forma tu pregunta